# Making sense of co-vector as stack of plane interpretation

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-forms

In page-149 of Tristan Needham's Visual Differential Geometry, the following picture is given:

> [image]

I was thinking of this interpretation, and  I think there is a problem with it. Suppose we have it that the length of vector is less than the spacing of vector? Then it would be that the one form should give zero when evaluated on a vector as it cuts through no planes, but if you actually evaluate the formula you get something non zero.

Eg: Consider the cartesian basis form $dz$, if we have a vector $v =.1\hat{k}$, then by the above interpretation, clearly $dz(v) $ should be zero since $v$ is too small to cut through any planes. But in actuality when we evaluated $dz(v)$ , we get $.1$

So am I misinterpreting the interpretation or are these type of issues known to exist with it?

Comment: You're misinterpreting. The discrete version of it is just to help you visualize. - it really is continuously valued. If you need more details, think about repeatedly doubling the number of planes, but dividing the count by two each time. This value will converge on the actual final value.

Comment: To add to @JonathanZsupportsMonicaC's comment, this *heuristic* is similar to drawing rectangles to visualize a Riemann sum to understand a definite integral or to draw a sequence of short segments connecting points on a curve to visualize arc length. They are not meant to be exactly correct, but rather to help make sense of the correct notion which involves a limiting process.